# To what extent is movement permissible in order to silent the phone if it starts ringing during the prayer?

Tags: salat, jamaat

While saying the prayers if someones phone (while in the pocket or kept on the ground) starts to ring, is it allowed to silent it through some minimal movement?

If so, what minimal movement in permissible if the phone is in the pocket, or if  one is standing or sitting and the phone is kept on the ground?

And if the phone is on the ground is it permissible to glance at just to see who's calling?

While at it, is it permissible to actually receive it and maybe even talk and then resume with the prayers?

*Note: this question applies to both individual and congregational prayers*

Comment: In my opinion, leave it in the car or in the house and avoid the situation all together. We are already slaves to this "always on connectivity" and at least in a house of worship we should be "online" and "connected" with only Allah and not others.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone mentioned, it is better to turn off the ringer or leave your phone outside the masjid but I am sure that you are not intentionally having a call while praying.

I read that (don't have a reference handy at the moment) while praying, one should not do that much movement that if someone else is looking at this person, cannot tell if that person is praying or not.

So during praying, if you put your hands in your pocket and start to look outside the window, that is not acceptable. If you sneeze or cough and try to put your one hand or elbow in front so germs won't spread in the masjid, that would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer to this question partly. Some scholars have said that one can silent his/her phone if it starts to ring in the pocket during the prayer but its always careful to turn it off before starting prayer.

I don't know what if the phone is on the ground. Its better not to touch it.

I don't think one can resume prayer after receiving the phone call.

Again, i humbly suggest to make ones life simple by putting away these distractions while praying. One is talking to whom (ALLAH, The Glorified) in the prayer and one wants to distract? Today, one needs to disengage as much as possible to make the prayer meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is something that did not happened in Prophet Muhammad's time, you will not an answer for that. Luckily, Allah has provided everyone of us a guidance and you can ask your consciousness about it. The important thing to note is that whatever you decide to do, either from other's comments or your own choice, it is something that can be a termed as as "prudent course of action" and not part of religion. You can choose one that feels right to you and keep an open mind to someone else has to say, and adopt that if you find it better.

To me, a phone ring can be very disturbing, especially in congregational prayers. Its better to make it silent during prayers, as soon as possible, even if you have break and restart your prayer. Hopefully it will close-by and you can do that with minimal action.

For individual prayer, if it distracts you, you should make it silent.